# Chocolatey GUI crash after trying to install Elixir

Tags: chocolatey

After trying to install Elixir, Chocolatey-gui froze, and after giving it an hour, I force closed it, and tried relaunching it, to get this: 
[image: Error Message]
`choco` in the command line still works fin. Does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: Can you confirm what version of ChocolateyGUI you are using?

Comment: @GaryEwanPark `ChocolateyGUI v0.13.2 is the latest version available based on your source(s).`

Comment: Can you try the latest pre release? Instructions for how to install are on the readme in the github repo. To see if the problem still exists.

Comment: @GaryEwanPark I'll give it a try as soon as possible. Got a lot of homework right now.

Comment: Not a problem at all.  The pre-release has had a lot of work done to it, and and number of problems have been corrected, so it could be possible that what you are seeing is simply no longer an issue.

Comment: @GaryEwanPark Where do I get the prerelease?

Comment: I tried `choco install ChocolateyGUI -source https://www.myget.org/F/chocolateygui/ -pre` and `choco install ChocolateyGUI -source https://www.myget.org/F/chocolateygui/ -pre --force`

Comment: Woops, I had to use upgrade. Duh.

Comment: @GaryEwanPark If you mark an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a known issue with the 0.13.x release of ChocolateyGUI.  We currently have a pre-release version of ChocolateyGUI that will correct this problem.  The full details of how to install the pre-release can be found on the project [readme](https://github.com/chocolatey/ChocolateyGUI#installation).

To install the pre-release version, you can run the command:

`choco install ChocolateyGUI -source https://www.myget.org/F/chocolateygui/ -pre`

**NOTE:** If you already have ChocolateyGUI installed, you will need to use `upgrade` instead.